# Maven SCM plugin, how set failOnError = false

Tags: maven, version-control, maven-scm, maven-scm-plugin

How can I configure Maven SCM plugin for ignoring errors during scm checkout? (Errors like "Permission denied" or other).
I know about configuration property `<failOnError>false</failOnError>` in other plugins, but this plugin does not have such option (or I didn't find it in documentation).

Here is my pom.xml section:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.9.5</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>checkout</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <failOnError>false</failOnError> <!-- It does not work! :( -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't think you can ignore SCM failures.

Comment: It's so sad. But how I can checkout scm when user has access rights on repository, and just skip it when it is not?

Comment: What would you build if you can't check out the resources ? It should just fail.

Comment: It is some additional resources besides main project. And only private users can clone those private git repository and works with them. All other users shouldn't be accepted to access on it.

Comment: You can put that plugin inside a profile block, and ask people with permissions to access those repos to enable the profile always on their `settings.xml`...  Or enable the profile from a command line parameter.

Comment: I did solved my problem by using `exec-maven-plugin` and it `successCodes` property instead of `maven-scm-plugin`. Thanks all.